# How can momentum trading strategies work if returns are not serially correlated?

Tags: time-series, trading, statistics, statistical-finance, momentum

Returns are demonstrably not serially correlated in most financial time series (Day 1 returns are uncorrelated to Day 2 returns etc.) . Since this is the case, how can momentum trading strategies work? What is the mathematical basis that can explain why momentum trading strategies work if there is not, in fact, a correlation between today's price movement and tomorrow's?

EDIT: As an example, take Bitcoin (it's what I'm looking at). I think it is intuitively/visually/conceptually obvious that there are strong momentum patterns. However, I have looked at autocorrelation in returns on timeframes ranging from 1 day to 30 days, and there is no autocorrelation. Perhaps my question should be the following: How can this "subjectively obvious" momentum be expressed, if not in autocorrelation of returns (which is absent)?

Comment: Time series momentum is about exploiting autocorrelation in returns. Historically there has been some serial correlation for individual stock returns for some horizons, though not so much for stock market indices. Also for fixed income and commodities returns. Cross-sectional momentum strategies can additionally exploit some cross-asset predictability patterns other than serial correlation.

Comment: You wrote: Day 1 returns are uncorrelated to Day 2 returns. Yes, but momentum strategies work at longer frequencies (6 months, for ex.) where there *may* be some correlation. But as fesman wrote it depends on the asset, the time period, etc.

Comment: @fesman I am not very familiar with cross-sectional momentum, but I have a conceptual grasp on time series momentum. Even though you say "Time series momentum is about exploiting autocorrelation in returns", that's exactly the issue I'm highlighting - for most financial instruments, there **is no** autocorrelation in returns. Take Bitcoin, for example. I think we can agree that it is very momentum-driven , but if you run some basic analysis, you'll find that last day's/week's/month's returns are not correlated to next day's/week's/month's returns. How can this be?

Comment: @noob2 There are momentum strategies that work on the timeframe of 1-2 weeks, but still no autocorrelation in returns. As I mentioned in my response to fesman, take Bitcoin (or any crypto). I think we can agree that it has strong momentum patterns on timeframes smaller than 6 months, yet I cannot statistically detect any autocorrelation in returns on timeframes from 1 to 30 days. How can this be?

Comment: @VladimirBelik Take a long panel of individual stock returns. Look at the correlation between one month stock returns and the return of the same stock for the past year. You should be able to detect some significant correlation between the two.

Answer (score 1):

Let $R_d$ be the return for day $d$.  Mean reversion means that $cor(R_d,R_{d+1})$, $cor(R_{d+1},R_{d+2})$, etc. are all negative--which is actually close to truth.  Under conditions not too hard to come up with, you can have $cor(R_d,R_{d+2})>0$ and $cor(R_d+R_{d+1},R_{d+2}+R_{d+3})>0$ simultaneously with mean reversion.  The last inequality is a two-day momentum.  As correctly stated in the comments, momentum is usually observed over longer horizons (and occasionally also intraday).

Correlation inequalities are useful and demonstrated by a quant interview question (among others in [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119821320)): *If the correlation between A and B is 90% and the correlation between B and C is 90%, what is the correlation between A and C?*

Comment: I understand the information you presented in your response. However, what I cannot understand is how momentum strategies can work when there **is no** detectable autocorrelation in returns. I am working with crypto, so I ran analysis on it. Even though there is (subjectively/intuitively) a clear momentum-driven aspect, I cannot detect any autocorrelation of returns on timeframes from 1 to 30 days. How can momentum strategies work while simultaneously not being any detectable autocorrelation in returns?

Comment: The idea is that subpopulation of returns may exhibit the autocorrelation you need, the question is how to know what the subpopulation is and how to detect that you are in it.

Comment: @HarryCrimmins Hm. Alright, so you're saying sometimes the autocorrelation exists, and sometimes not. But so then indeed, how would you detect this in an unbiased way? Of course if I look at a graph and just analyze the part where there is a trend, naturally there will be a correlation. But how could you independently detect this?

Comment: My data are in equities, not in crypto.  Serial autocorrelations do exist in equities, but the the signal-to-noise ratio is small, not least due to quant competition keeping tradable signals close to balancing trading costs.  People trade by using multiple signals combined, but even then the market is very competitive and mostly arbed out.  Crypto is not arbed out this much yet, but you can probably guess the direction it goes.

Comment: @Vladimir Belik: If a momentum strategy did generate positive returns over some period $[T_1, T_2]$, then by the definition of auto-correlation, there had to be positive auto-correlation over that period. Of course, whether this exists in general and whether it exists for all stocks or just a subset is a different issue. My point is that, the following is not possible:  a momentum strategy generated significant + returns over some period and + autocorrelation did not exist during the same period. Note also that testing for it statistically is not synonymous with the existence of it.

Comment: @markleeds If you look at just the days when there was a trend, of course there will be an autocorrelation of the returns (and a momentum strat would be profitable). However, I'm saying over 5 years of BTC data, there is a momentum strategy that generates significant returns (beating the market) BUT the autocorrelation of daily returns corr(Rt, Rt+1) is like 0.03.. basically nonexistent. Run an autocorrelation of BTC daily returns - you will find no correlation. Would you therefore state that a BTC momentum strat can't exist?

Comment: Of course a momentum strategy can exist. There are a few reasons: (1) very low correlation may still be significant enough to bet on (2) rather than looking at the average autocorrelation for the entire period, momentum strategies might be predicated on something like zscore > 1 returns for X% of days in the last moving window of Y days. Momentum isn't betting on every single move persisting, maybe you limit your bets to a subset of moves that are more likely to persist. How you find that subset is the hard bit, people are unlikely to share exact details.

Comment: Validimir: I'm not clear on how you say 0.03 is non-existent. ( that could be a lot depending on the return numbers ).  Also, you have to be careful of what causes what. Suppose during that 5 year period, you had one big positive move near the end of the period. Then that could give you a  positive return but probably not translate into much as far as positive autocorrelation. So, you'd have to figure out the cause of the positive return over the period because it may not be due to positive autocorrelation.

Comment: @HarryCrimmins  I understand and agree with point 1 (though R squared = 0.03 seems truly negligible). (2) I understand your idea here, however - I just tested the 1-day autocorrelation of **just** the returns when my momentum strategy gives a signal. Still no correlation. In fact, I just ad-hoc hand-picked a 100 day period when the price of BTC rose very strongly (around 100%) and ran the daily autocorrelation on those 100 days and **still** there is none (literally a negative r squared). I'm not sure what to make of this. What is the mathematical explanation behind what's going on here?

Comment: @markleeds Would you say an R squared of 0.03 is not negligible? In my experience, you can generate 2 sets of random numbers and they will have that kind of correlation. I think we can confidently say such a low level is effectively non-existent. I sort of see what you're saying here. However, I genuinely challenge you to find any considerable period of time in the BTC time series where the R squared of the returns is larger than, say, 0.2 . It seems very oddly difficult, given how "obviously" momentum-driven BTC is.

Comment: I think large or small depends on the magnitudes of the returns. I don't know if you're calculating a daily correlation or a monthly correlation ( or a yearly correlation even ) etc but suppose the average daily returns werre .0010 so 10 basis points and the correlation was 0.03. That would seem not so small to me. On the other hand, if the average daily return was .01 so 100 basis points then 0.03 would seem small. So, I think the correlation has to be looked at in tandem with the magnitude of the returns because the smaller the returns are, the less correlation one would expect.

Comment: I just saw your other question about how can BTC returns have a daily 0.03 correlation and still generate positive returns over the market. Take a step function where the price hangs around the same level for most of the first year and then at  the end of the first year there's a large jump up in price and then the price hangs around that level. Then, at the end of year 2, there's another large + jump in price and then the price hangs around there and so on and so forth until the end of year 5. So, there won't be a large + autocorrelation  but the returns will be pretty decent.

Answer (score 0):

The crux of the answer is that a non-significant serial correlation will produce significant price action. Granger and Newbold (1973) showed that completely unbiased random walks of returns generated statistically significant "trends" in price more often than not :-)

[The rising variance over time violates the stationarity of price, if you want to get formal]

That is the essence of the problem here ;-)
DEM

Comment: So, are you saying that even small serial correlation will "add up" to produce significant price action? Or are you saying that even with non-existent serial correlation, sometimes there will just happen to be big price movements randomly (by chance)? Or am I missing the point completely? :-P

Comment: The former. Completely random walks WILL generate (fake) trends, as a matter of course.

Comment: So okay, I understand that completely random walks WILL (by chance) generate trends. However, then the second part of my central question remains - if there is no true underlying mechanism/driver of the trends that (randomly) occur in a financial series, why do momentum strategies work? That would suggest momentum strategies pick up on spurious price changes, meaning there is **not** a tendency for existing trends to continue, meaning these strategies should (on average) fail to outperform the underlying asset, but this is not the case. Do you see my dilemma?

Comment: Then we are in agreement :-) the point then being that a statistically significant momentum effect in price need not have a significant autocorrelation! If randomness can generate trends, then how distinguish those from insignificant momentum drift??? That's the essence of the problem here, in a nutshell.

Comment: Oh I see your point! Let me propose an experiment. I will randomly sample with replacement from the distribution of BTC returns to create synthetic time series, where the series has same distribution as real BTC but returns in random order. I will do this many times, and each time I will measure the max drawdown. H1: Trends in BTC are spurious effects of random chance. If so, the average max drawdown of simulated series will be nearly same as real max drawdown. H2: Trends in BTC have a "true" momentum aspect, and therefore the real BTC series will have greater max drawdown than simulated one.

Comment: I ran the experiment. True 5 year max drawdown: 83% . Mean of 10,000 simulated max drawdowns: 66% , with standard deviation of 11% . Not super conclusive, but the true value is around 2 SDs out from the simulated mean. What do you make of this? I want to design another test, but I think this is potentially indicative that there is something more at play beyond random chance, even though there is no autocorrelation of returns.

Comment: @demully: I get your point about a random walk sometimes generating a trend so that the price can have a trend in it but it's spurious. What I don't get is why the autocorrelation calculated from the price trend can't be significant  also?   The sample acf  can also show significant autocorrelations. In fact, in Stephen Taylor's text, "Modelling Financial Time Series", this is exactly what he tries to exploit except that he doesn't claim it's spurious. (unfortunately, his book is out of print).  If you're saying that the spurious nature makes their future existence less reliable, I agree.